# OBIEE BI Administration (RPD) Error

Tags: obiee, oracle-bi

I am creating a repository(RPD) using oracle BI Administration and datasource is SQL Server 2012. I successfully created connection pool also imported Meta Data. But when perform the row count operation on any table which is imported in physical layer. following error occurs:

[Error message Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xze0C.png)

I am not able to find out the reason behind this. Description of the datasource and etc are following:-
OBIEE Version - OBIEE 12c (12.2.0.0.0)
data source - SQL Server 2012 (AdventureWorks2012)
connection - ODBC 3.5, SQL Server Native Client 11.0

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the table name is not correctly qualified in your Connection Pool settings.

If it is, then you should ensure that, after logging directly into the SQL Server using your Connection Pool settings, you can perform a row count of the table in question.